# How do I add a class on click that keeps working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I've got a coin on my page that the user clicks and it should keep flipping due to this added class each time it is clicked.

I'm using animate.css with the class "flip"

So I've got:

```
 function coinToss() {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);


        $("#coin").toggleClass('flip');




        if(number == 0) {
            var value = $("#headsText").val(); 
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Heads";
            $('#resultText').html($("#headsText").val());
        }
        else if(number == 1) {
            var value = $("#tailsText").val(); 
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Tails";
            $('#resultText').html($("#tailsText").val());
    }

}
```

With this the coin only flips the first time. I need it to keep flipping every click.

Comment: How are you using `coinToss()`

Comment: this  `$("#coin").addClass("flip");` not should be inside `else` condition?

Comment: You have an error in `else`. Should be `else { ... code ... }`!

Comment: Then there must be something with the class `.flip` does it produce a flip on *every* remove or add? Can you show that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/nGfbH/3/

Answer (score 3):

Just use [**toggleClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), the method means if matched elements do not have the class name, then add it; if matched elements already have the class name, then remove it.

```
function coinToss() {
    $("#coin").toggleClass('flip');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2Ugdw/)

Comment: But then the next time it is clicked the class is removed and nothing happens.

Comment: @thomasp423, You need to show How you are using `coinToss()` function to help you

Comment: No. When I click it the first time it adds the class. THen the next click removes and no animation. Then I click again and it adds and animates.

Comment: @Satpal I need the user to click and the coin to flip on EVERY click

Answer (score 2):

Use [**toggleClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for toggle between class , and [**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) for execute in every 1 second

```
var inter;
function coinToss() {
    $("#coin").toggleClass('flip');
}
$('.button').click(function(){inter=setInterval(coinToss,1000)});
$('.stop').click(function(){clearInterval(inter)});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/nGfbH/3/)

Comment: This keeps the coin flipping without the user clicking it. I need it only on click.

Comment: @thomasp423 "need it to keep flipping" loosely interpretated!!

Answer (score 0):

This should be  `$("#coin").addClass("flip");` inside `else` condition.

```
function coinToss() {      
 if($("#coin").hasClass("flip")){
      $(this).removeClass("flip")
 }
else {
   $("#coin").addClass("flip");
}
```